# How to find files which are larger than 500GB in SHELL script

Tags: shell, putty

I tried searching some files in putty which are older than 80 days using shell script.the folder size is greater than 100GB.and this command is giving folowing exception

```
        find /data/local_0/ -type f -name "*.txt" -mtime +80
```

Exception: "value Defined for datatype is too large"

Comment: Are you searching for files larger than 100GB or 500GB or files which are older than 80days??

Comment: i'm searching for files which are older than 80 days..and the folder size is greater than 500 GB.and inside this folder contains txt files

Answer (score 0):

You can use stat command to know everything about file. Just to demonstrate, i have written simple script, which will find the files which have size larger than 500GB in a given directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
   echo "[USAGE] : $0 <path>" 
   exit 1
fi
echo "Files having size more than 500GB"
count=0
for i in $1/*
do
     #get the size, it will be in byte nd convert it to GB
     size=$(stat -c %s $i)
     size=`expr $size / 1024 \* 1024`;
     if [ $size -ge 500 ]; then
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        echo ">>> $i"
     fi
done

if [ $count -eq 0 ] ; then
     echo "No files with size more than 500"
fi

exit 0
```

You can extend this to traverse through all the directory recursively [use ls -R to get files]

Answer (score 0):

```
find /data/local_0 -mount -type f -name "*.txt" -mtime +80 -size +500G
```

Use -mount to avoid descend directories on other filesystems.

Comment: in my folder (data/local_0) contains more than 13000000 number of files..so can you please tell me how to delete it using SHELL